# Type definition: An array of a certain type at least with e.g. 2 elements

Tags: typescript, type-definition

Maybe that's a stupid question, but I would like to know if there is a possibility to say, "foo" must have at least 2 array elements of type "Foo"?

```
let foo: Array<Foo>; // how to say at least 2 Foos?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [rest element in a tuple type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#rest-elements-in-tuple-types):

```
let foo: [Foo, Foo, ...Foo[]];
```

And the compiler will enforce it:

```
declare const f: Foo;
foo = [f, f, f]; // okay
foo = [f, f]; // okay
foo = [f]; // error, property "1" is missing
foo = []; // error, properties "0" and "1" are missing
```

Of course, the compiler won't easily be able to verify that some arbitrary `Foo[]` matches this, even if you do the "obvious" length check:

```
declare const fooArray: Foo[];
foo = fooArray; // error, can't verify
if (fooArray.length >= 2) {
  foo = fooArray; // error, still can't verify
}
```

So you might find yourself in need of something like a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to convert a `Foo[]` to a `[Foo, Foo, ...Foo[]]`:

```
function isAtLeastTwoFoos(x: Foo[]): x is [Foo, Foo, ...Foo[]] {
  return x.length >= 2;
}
```

And then you can test that way.

```
if (isAtLeastTwoFoos(fooArray)) {
  foo = fooArray; // okay
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAuKBnYAJwEsA7AcygF8BuAKDoBsJhMcoBteOAGlgT4A6Ydw4BdMfToATCAGNGAQ0LQ5cUgUy5u9LIhQcMfI5klQA9OahwA1opB09yTiYxnL1uw6cG3NC1YQhIRwhHxgIZCEoFAARACMsVDEeFAAtil4ZOSOCM7i-h5BIWFQEXBRwMQQqbEADEmKpNJxiVDK0Bl4WRQMsgodUGoarHoAgsH22ggFufpscBOE9oWBwaF8ck0A5KwAbkHEGA5HUAAU45MggswUwAAWUAB8KABMAJRodFALzpfLIFWUGKG3wVUYjCGO32h2OdCoDAwAFdSHIqupkngxsAADIQRQEAAqAHc4Nw8GcAB7TODid64SmYzjcPgsqDCQSiCRfH4qYBIwikKCUm4QO6PF5QV70BF0U5nFLYvEE4AkskICn-ezvT6ob6-FBawEBTz2eF0IA)

Comment: Now I finally understand type guard functions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not modify the length of the array in your code, a tuple type (as in [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57117431/1426891)) is a good idea.

However, you can unset array elements in a variety of ways—`shift`, `pop`, `splice`, `filter`—which will cause your array to no longer match your expectations. Though this isn't necessarily different than (say) unsafely putting an unrelated `Bar` element in `Array<Foo>`, you might still be able to defeat the type's safety using only runtime calls, which may not be a good idea.